# Error: calling arguments in user functions using quosures

Tags: r

I am trying to create cross tables using weights::wtd.chi.sq.

The data:

```
data_in <- read_table2("Q50_1   Q50_2   Q38 Q90 pov gender  wgt1 wgt2
never   always   Yes 2   High    M   1.3 0.4
sometimes   always   No  2   Med F   0.4 0.2
always   sometimes   Yes 4   Low F   1.2 0.7
never   never   No  2   High    M   0.5 0.7
always   always   No  4   High    M   0.7 0.8
sometimes   never   Yes 3   Low F   0.56 0.3
sometimes   never   Yes 2   Med F   0.9 0.1
")
```

x_tab function that feeds into another function:

```
xtab_func <- function(dat, col, target, wgt){
  col <- rlang::as_string(ensym(col))
  target <- rlang::as_string(ensym(target))
  wgt <- rlang::as_string(ensym(wgt))
  wtd.chi.sq(dat[[target]],dat[[col]], weight = dat[[wgt]])
  
}
```

Running it gives:

```
xtab_func(data_in, 'Q50_1','pov','wgt1')
    Chisq        df   p.value 
7.3395092 4.0000000 0.1189981
```

Now I am looping through a vector of columns to repeat this for tabulation for each column. The error happens when I try to call target and wgt within the xtab function above. I've tried 3 different ways but none of them work.

```
crosstab <- function(dat, target, columns, wgt,target_name, school_type){
  # browser()
  target <- rlang::as_string(ensym(target))
  print(target)
  wgt <- rlang::as_string(ensym(wgt))
  
  target_name <- enquo(target_name)
  school_type <- enquo(school_type)
  
  d <- list()

  for (i in columns){
    # OPTION 1
    # x <- xtab_func(dat, i, !!target, !!wgt)
    # OPTION 2
    x <- xtab_func(dat, i, target, wgt)
    # OPTION 3 
    # x <- xtab_func(dat, i, dat[[target]],dat[[wgt]])
    x$i <- i

    d[[i]] <- x
    df <- do.call(rbind, d) 
  }
  return(df)

  
}
```

When I run this I could see the chi values for the columns by pov...

```
cols <- data_in %>% select(starts_with("Q"))
cols <- names(cols)
crosstab(data_in,'pov',cols, 'wgt1', 'pov','trad')
```

But I get these errors:

```
 Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols 
 OR 
  Error in model.frame.default(formula = weight ~ var1 + var2) : 
  invalid type (NULL) for variable 'var1'
```

Any idea how I call those variables? Thank you!

Comment: What is group from the output.  I don't find that `map_dfr(cols, ~ xtab_func(data_in, !!.x, 'pov', 'wgt1')) %>% mutate(group_level = 'pov', school_type = 'trad')`

Comment: @akrun thanks, I corrected the user function! The same issue remains

Comment: Have you tried the code I commented `map_dfr(cols, ~ xtab_func(data_in, !!.x, 'pov', 'wgt1')) %>% mutate(group_level = 'pov', school_type = 'trad')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me at all why you are trying to use all the `rlang` stuff when you are just passing character values to your functions. This could be greatly simplified to

```
xtab_func <- function(dat, col, target, wgt){
  weights::wtd.chi.sq(dat[[target]],dat[[col]], weight = dat[[wgt]])
}
```

and

```
crosstab <- function(dat, target, columns, wgt,target_name, school_type){
  d <- list()
  for (i in columns){
    x <- as.data.frame(as.list(xtab_func(dat, i, target, wgt)))
    x$i <- i
    d[[i]] <- x
  }
  df <- do.call(rbind, d) 
  return(df)
}
```

Just use `[[]]` with character values to index into your data.

Answer (score 1):

With the OP's default function `xtab_func`, we can modify the `crosstab` to

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
crosstab <- function(dat, target, columns, wgt,target_name, school_type){
  purrr::map_dfr(columns, ~ {
    xtab_func(dat, !!.x, !!target, !!wgt) 
  })  
}
```

-testing

```
crosstab(data_in,'pov', cols, 'wgt1', 'pov','trad')
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Chisq    df p.value
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1  7.34     4   0.119
2  6.02     4   0.198
3  1.47     2   0.480
4  4.83     4   0.306
```